# figuring out the proper location of defining my javascript in drupal for specific page manipulation

Tags: javascript, drupal

First time touching Drupal 9 and I have got a site working locally on my computer using Docksal , Docker on Ubuntu 22.04  WSL 2 where I can test/make any changes. I have a Frequently Asked Question page and View,Edit , API etc options at the top of the page which looks like this. Here's [some glimpse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVnN7.jpg) of how it looks like:

This FAQ page after inspecting in browser looks like this:

```
<ul class="list--faq">
   <li aria-controls="faq-10" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">How can I contact with questions about your services?</li>
   <li id="faq-1" style="display: block; transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;" data-slide-toggle="true">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
</ul>
```

I'm wondering how to handle this page if I want to do something like the following:

An external link will bring user to this page with a URL containing #faq-1
and based on that id I want to open the accordian on this FAQ page so I was thinking to define a Javascript somewhere to handle this and wondering where to start. Please let me know if I can answer any questions. Thanks

Here's what I was thinking:
To define JS [like this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843) maybe.

I already have a `*.libraries.yml` file in my directory structure so I was just thinking of adding a new JS over there. Is that the right way to proceed?

I see a `JS` folder in there with a `modules` directory containing multiple JS files and a `main.js` inside JS files which basically calls all th eexported functions inside each of the JS files located inside modules folder. Is that the way to define it over there with `Drupal.behaviors ....` `atach ..` etc? I was wondering how will my new JS file would know that it is handling a specific page content of the particular page shown in the image above?
Should I just edit the HTML from the User Interface  and then select the id and just refer to that using jQuery or something else?

Comment: "I see a `JS` folder in there with […]" where is "there"? Is this some custom module you have written or something else?

Comment: `JS` directory is inside this location `docroot/sites/default/themes/site/mycompany-theme/` I didn't create anything as I am getting familiar with this stuff to make the changes. And inside `js` folder, I have `main.js` and `modules` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have many pages where certain css or js is used only on that one, or a few pages.  Instead of loading it for every page, I implemented the themename_preprocess_node hook in the themename.theme file, and loaded the resources only for the pages that needed them.

First, define your libraries in your *.libraries.yml file. My theme is named hhc, so in the hhc.theme file I added this function.  Something similar should work for you.

```
function hhc_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  // get a hold of the node object
  $node = $variables['node'];

  switch ($node->id()) {
    case 1:  /* Retreat Dates page */
    case 5:  /* Prices page */
      $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'hhc/tables';
      break;
    case 21:  /* About Center page, 6 images block at bottom*/
      $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'hhc/photo-gallery';
      $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'hhc/video';
      break;
    case 37:  /* 12 Day Retreats*/
    case 38:  /* 9 Day Retreats*/
    case 39:  /* Personalized Retreats*/
      $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'hhc/dailyschedule';
      break;
  }
}
```

You can easily determine the nodeid of a page by putting it in edit mode and looking at the url in the browser.